# Crosswalk not working with files upload

Tags: android

Hello great stackoverflow. I just develop a small app and wrap it with crosswalk  because of its good performance. everything work fine and the browser performance was excellent on android 4+. The issue now is that crosswalk does not allow me to upload file from the android app. when i click on upload, it will say "No app can perform this action".

am just using

```
<input type=file name="image">
```

Any solution to this?. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on **Android 6+**.

After install app on device/emulator by default all permissions turned off.

You need turn on storage permission.
Go to **Settings** > **Apps** > **Your app** > **Permissions**.

But if you need to request to permissions in runtime then use [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions)